# IdentationError showing when i try to print tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('Home.html','r')as html_file:
    content=html_file.read()
    print(content)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
   tags = soup.find('h5') #error showing here
   print(tags)#and here
```

can anybody tell me why show identation error from here. And please tell me which package i have to install or what kind of things i have to do for run this one.

Comment: The line beginning with `tags =` is indented 1 space less than the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally indented the first 4 lines of the with statement with 1 space.
Here's a fix:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('Home.html','r')as html_file:
   content=html_file.read()
   print(content)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
   tags = soup.find('h5') 
   print(tags)
```

Comment: Thanks I got my answer.